# What is the best way to validate every single file on an external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, kernel-panic

My mac is having a kernel panic every time I try to time machine this external drive.

I've tried disk utility but I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually check for much, except maybe for some directory structure. The scan is maybe only a few minutes long and it reports everything has fine.

Is there a command or app that will actually read every single file in the disk and report any corruption or IO error?

Comment: You’ve made a rather large jump from kernel panic = file corruption.  Before embarking on such a tedious project of validating every single file, how about evaluating the kernel panic because it could be something with the USB bus, the USB enclosure, the drive itself, etc.

Comment: Did you run First Aid?

Comment: In order to tell if a file has been corrupted, you need an original to compare against. (This is why people use ZFS, `zpoil scrub` ftw!) Do you have such a backup?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, if you run First Aid on a volume, Disk Utility verifies all the contents of that volume only. This is from [this site](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/repair-a-storage-device-dskutl1040/mac). First thing I'd do if run first aid on your drive. It takes about 30 minutes to verify my drive.